# adding a subclass of view in the main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

Here is part of main layout file:

```
<FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "center" >
    <view
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        class="com.drawshapes.DrawCircles"></view>
</FrameLayout>
```

It gives me a compile error. I am not sure if I am approaching it correctly. Should I be looking at fragments? or possibly adding another activity file? Or a layout file?
There is also a snippet from google that starts with something like this:

```
     <com.drawshapes.DrawCircles>
      android. .....
     </>
```

But I have no idea where to put them, if they should go into a resource file or create another layout file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: paste your DrawCircle class and error log

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <com.drawshapes.DrawCircles
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: that tag still didn't work. The error is pointing to the setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); in the main activity class.

Comment: where do you put `DrawCircles` class? is it library or module?

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong. It turns out that to add a subclass of view as a custom view in XML, we have to implement this constructor:

public MyView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

When implementing subclass of view to be used in layout XML file, use this format:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<com.drawshapes.DrawCircles
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

(Thanks to dotkebi.)

Also I must implement this constructor:

```
// gets called when adding this sub-view class from XML
  public DrawShapes(Context con, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(con, attrs);
    Log.v("constructor", "context & attributes ");
    myList.add(new Shape(120, 170, 21,"square"));
}
```